# NLog not working in release mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nlog

I am using NLog to log the exceptions in my asp.net mvc (C#) application.

NLog is not working in release mode. The same is working when running in debug mode.

What may be the problem? Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Is the nlog config file included as part of your release build?

Comment: So if you run both locally (i.e., just hitting ctrl-f5), it fails in release?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: When i run in local with release mode, its not working. The error is like "Its not resolving the ILogger".

Comment: Have you set throwExceptions to true?

Comment: Hi Prasad. Did you resolve this? I'm having the same problem on my MVC 3 app.

Comment: @niaher, i am using http://code.google.com/p/elmah for error handling now. This is very useful. Take a look at this, it may work for you

Comment: Yea, i am using Elmah too, along with NLog. They have different purposes.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem as you:

- ASP.NET MVC 3
- .NET 4
- IIS 7
- Release Mode

I tried changing directories, and changing permissions to no avail.  I even tried enabling the internal logging but even that didn't work!  No failures, no exceptions, nothing!

After doing some more investigating, I found the solution.  **For some reason, NLog wasn't loading the config file AT ALL.**  I realized this after I programmatically enabled the internal logging.  The internal logging reported this:

```
2012-02-13 11:34:40.3181 Debug Targets for MyMvcController by level:
2012-02-13 11:34:40.3181 Debug Trace =>
2012-02-13 11:34:40.3181 Debug Debug =>
2012-02-13 11:34:40.3181 Debug Info =>
2012-02-13 11:34:40.3181 Debug Warn =>
2012-02-13 11:34:40.3181 Debug Error =>
2012-02-13 11:34:40.3181 Debug Fatal =>
```

This was basically saying that there were no targets defined for any of the log levels!  Definitely not correct!

My NLog configuration file was as simple as it could be (and it was set to Copy to Output Directory):

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
     <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
  </configSections>
  <!-- Other XML Sections -->
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/MyApplication.log" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

I'm still not sure exactly **why** this was happening, but moving the NLog configuration into the web.config directly resolved the problem.

See also: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#configuration-file-format

Comment: I did this, and now it says the web.config file is invalid

Comment: @Tuco What does your config look like now?

Comment: Please disregard it's working now, perhaps you should mention that a section declaration is needed https://gist.github.com/kishorejangid/4004715

Answer (score 2):

I think you should provide to your publish directory IIS_IUSRS to Write Permission.

Answer (score 1):

set up environment variables:NLOG_INTERNAL_LOG_LEVEL and NLOG_INTERNAL_LOG_FILE, rerun your release build then check the log file see what's wrong

Comment: I tried this, but no dice.  It works locally in debug mode, but when I deploy in release mode, even the internal logging doesn't work.  I'm pretty sure my permissions are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone, who is not sure about 'why nlog is not working in prod environment':

1. Go to Nlog.config file
2. SET throwExceptions="**true**" in **nlog** tag
   and start debugging with proper errors.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer nlog config to config file of your application (web.config for example), and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your target file saves within a "/logs/" folder. See below

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
```

I tried to log into "root/log.log" and was not working, then tried "root/logs/log.log" and worked

Below full config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log" >


  <!-- optional, add some variabeles
  https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables
  -->
  <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>

  <!-- 
  See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file 
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>

    <!-- 
    add your targets here 
    See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Targets for possible targets.
    See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers for the possible layout renderers.
    -->

    <!--
    Writing events to the a file with the date in the filename. -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->

    <!--
    Write all events with minimal level of Debug (So Debug, Info, Warn, Error and Fatal, but not Trace)  to "f"-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="f" />

  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've configured NLog in the right way, like the other answers suggest, Try one of these

1. Write Permission for your Server

   If you are using IIS, give *WRITE* permission for user **IIS_IUSRS** for your log folder.
2. Constructor

   ```
    public LoggerService() {
        _logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

   The path for nlog.config could be different for you. Mine was on the same folder
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the NLog InternalLogger from code, so you can rule out the issue with correct deployment of NLog.config:

```cs
// enable internal logging to the console
NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogToConsole = true;
     
// enable internal logging to a file
NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogFile = "c:\\nlog-internal.txt"; // On Linux one can use "/home/nlog-internal.txt"
    
// set internal log level
NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Debug;
    
// Perform test output, ensure first NLog Logger is created after InternalLogger is enabled.
NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("Test").Info("Hello World");
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Another thing worth checking is the write permission of your log directory and/or files.

Permission error, or any other error, will show up in the internal log if enabled. This is how I set up my `NLog.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"

      <!-- setting to True will break your application so be careful  -->
      throwExceptions="false"

      <!-- change level to your preference  -->
      internalLogLevel="Error" internalLogFile="c:\your-path\nlog-internal.log">


      <!-- your NLog settings  -->
      <!-- ...  -->

</nlog>
```