# ASP.NET Framework - Application fails to Build on Release Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Windows Service in ASP.NET Framework-4.8. I use Visual Studio 2022 as the IDE.

Everything is working fine. If I build using debug, it works fine. But If I change the dropdown from debug to release, I got these errors:

1. Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
   Error   CS0103  The name 'NLog' does not exist in the current context   MyService   C:\MyService\Models\Postingentries.cs   97  Active

It highlights NLOG in:

```
else
{
    Logger.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Error, $"ERROR IN POSTING. PostEntries METHOD. REASON: RESP_CODE = {post.ResponseCode}. ERROR TEXT = {post.ErrorText} ------ {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(post.ErrorText))
{
    Logger.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Error, $"ERROR IN POSTING. PostEntries METHOD. REASON: RESP_CODE = {post.ResponseCode}. ERROR TEXT = {post.ErrorText} ------ {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
}
```

and also Highlights NLog and LogManager wherever they are found.

2. Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
   Error   CS0103  The name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context    MyrService  C:\MyService\Models\Postingentries.cs   600 Active

it highlights:

using Newtonsoft.Json;

and

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData)
```

and

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SingleTransferResponseDto>(resp)
```

When I checked installed packages, NLog-4.3.10 is installed.

Kindly help resolve the errors

```
using NLog;

namespace MyService.Models
{
    class Logger
    {
        private static readonly NLog.Logger Nlog = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public static void Log(LogLevel level, string message)
        {
            Nlog.Log(level, System.Environment.NewLine + message + System.Environment.NewLine + "-------------------------------------------------------------");

        }
    }
}
```

NB:
Everything works fine when I build on debug. But the error comes when I build on Release

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959135/nlog-not-working-in-release-mode

Comment: Check the "Configuration Manager" that the platform are identical for Debug/Release. And that all projects have the "build" checked.